# Bukkit Plugin for broadcasting message string issue

Tags: java, maven, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to make a small plugin for my server (CraftBukkit 1.8.8) to broadcast a simple custom message to the server when someone donates on our website.

The plugin itself works in concept, except for one issue. It won't include ANY whitespace / spaces in the message, so "hello world" it broadcasted as "helloworld" which is not what I want.

This is my first time trying to program using java, or for bukkit plugins in general, so I am still VERY new to this. Most articles I see regarding broadcasts don't touch on my issue, so any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
public final class DonateBroadcast extends JavaPlugin {

    public void onEnable() {

        System.out.println("DonateBroadcast enabled.");

    }

    public void onDisable() {

        System.out.println("DonateBroadcast disabled.");

    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String cmd, String[] args) {
        if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("dbcast")) {
            if((sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage("This command must be executed by the console");
            } else {
                if(args.length == 0) {
                    System.out.println(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You need to type in a message!");
                } else {
                    getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.GREEN + "WEB" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "] " + ChatColor.GOLD + message(args));
                }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String message(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        builder.append(args[i]);
        builder.append(" ");
        return builder.toString();      
    }
}
```

Please note that I coded this following a tutorial on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Well after playing around, I apparently forgot to add brackets for the for statement at:

```
public String message(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        builder.append(args[i]);
        builder.append(" ");
        return builder.toString();      
    }
```

so after changing it to:

```
public String message(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
          builder.append(args[i]);
          builder.append(" ");
        }
        return builder.toString();      
    }
```

it now works without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, `builder.append(" ")` isn't working out for you, when I was making my plugin with my own /msg command, I had the same problem. But I found a different method. So instead of

```
public String message(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    builder.append(args[i]);
    builder.append(" ");
    return builder.toString();      
}
```

Use:

```
public String message(String[] args){
    String string = "";
    for (int i = 0; i != args.length; i++){
        msg += args[i] + " ";
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Hopefully this works!